# When I get a child node and access its data, what data will I also queried?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
{message:{
  "id1":{
    "name":"name1"
},
  "id2":{
    "name":"name2"
},
  "id3":{
    "name":"name3"
}... and so on
}}
```

Let say I am having firebase data structure like above, now I am trying to get the first id's value (e.g its name) by using child("id1")...value(). Will I potentially access and query data of "id2" or the rest of the nodes on the same level?

Excluding the cost of storing data in the database, will it cost more to query a single node (getting all its inner values) when the number of nodes in "message" is starting to grow?

Comment: You can maintain a data structure inside your application, read it once at constructor and later get,update your data whenever you want. and at the end of the application update firebase.

but this way you lose the realtime feature

Answer (score 0):

You have to do like this is you want all child value on same level

```
firebase.child("message").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot innerDataSanpShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
      //DataSnapshot of inner Childerns mean id1, id2.... so on
      String name = innerDataSnapShot.child("name").getValue().toString();
     } 
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

}
});
```

other way is that you can get whole data of message and after that you can get every child data by this

```
   dataSnapshot.child("id1"). getValue();
```

Comment: not really my question, I want to avoid touching nodes other than "id1" in my case. I am interested whether it is appropriate to have a master node "message" storing all the messages regardless of which chatroom it belongs. If I already have particular chatroomid storing which messageid does it belong.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your target platform, I will assume its a web based application. In order to execute a query for the data at the node in question, you may do something like the following:

```
var data = snapshot.val();
var userMessage = data.id1.message;
```

This simple example will show the message at that particular location, which you will need to substitute the 'id1' in the correct format. You will not call the data from other levels as you use the 'id1' value to pinpoint the node you wish to query data from.

In terms of your second question, I don't believe it will cost you more by querying a single node as the database grows, providing you make a query at that particular location. Of course, if you add a loop then this will change things depending on the size of your database.